# Node.JS - Promises do not wait to resolve

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I am using the [dockerode](https://github.com/apocas/dockerode) for manipulate docker from node.js. The library it self is not the problem but i am have issues with PROMISE. It seems the promise do not wait to resolve.

The code below I expected the output will be:

```
Start
Middle // (or Err if docker does not running)
End
```

But I am receiving:

```
Start
End
Middle
```

It seems the promise is not waiting to continue the javascript running flow. What I am doing wrong?

```
const Docker = require('dockerode')
let docker = new Docker();

console.log('Start');
let promise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    docker.listContainers({all: true}, function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            reject(err)
        } else {
            resolve(data);
        }
    });
});

promise.then(function (data) {
    console.log('Middle');
}, function (err) {
    console.log('Err');
});

console.log('End');
```

Copy and paste this code on https://npm.runkit.com/dockerode or see the result here: https://runkit.com/embed/y3wvg6ktecb9

Comment: Add `await` before `promise.then` (and wrap the whole thing in `async function`).

Comment: Thats how a promise works... resolving when ready which could be years later after your two synchronous console.log()...

Comment: @torazaburo not necessary, that's just syntax sugar for promises.

Comment: @WilomGfx I know exactly what it is. I am saying that that is one approach to writing code which waits for the promise to fulfill before proceeding on to `console.log('End')`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your output is correct, you're misunderstanding how promises work.

Promises are [asynchronous](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises), they run on a [different (microtask) tick](https://jakearchibald.com/2015/tasks-microtasks-queues-and-schedules/) within the same task in the [event loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop). This means no promise is resolved while a synchronous piece of code is running.

```js
// output 'a', 'c', 'b'
console.log('a');
Promise.resolve().then(() => console.log('b'));
console.log('c');
```

Furthermore, even if promises were synchronous, the call to `docker.listContainers` is asynchronous and receives a callback to call when the operation is successful.

If you want to wait for a promise, either put the code that you want to run after a promise is resolved in a `then` callback of that promise:

```js
// output 'a', 'b', 'c'
console.log('a');
Promise.resolve()
   .then(() => console.log('b'))
   .then(() => console.log('c'));
```

Or wrap your code in an [async function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) and `await` the promise:

```js
// output 'a', 'b', 'c'
(async () => {
  console.log('a');
  await Promise.resolve().then(() => console.log('b'))
  console.log('c');
})()
```

Comment: Just a typo in the code comments: the second and third snippets output 'a', 'b', 'c'.

Comment: Yeah. I misunderstood the Promise. I am migrating to node.js and some concepts are really new for me. But thank you. It was very well explained.